# Print List of tables on same page as table of contents (scrreprt)

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

Since my toc is one and a half pages long and my lof/lot only contains four items, I would like to print the lot/lof on the same page as the table of contents.
A M(n)WE looks like

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc]{scrreprt}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\chapter{test}
\begin{table}\centering
\begin{tabular}{c}
a
\end{tabular}
\caption{test}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Any help is appreciated. I could not find an appropriate answer to this issue here. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `listof=leveldown` to set the lot/lof as sections.

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc,listof=leveldown]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\blinddocument
\begin{table}\centering
\begin{tabular}{c}
Text
\end{tabular}
\caption{Example}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Another possibility is redefining `\clearpage` locally:

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
{%
  \renewcommand\clearpage{}%
  \listoftables%
}
\blinddocument
\begin{table}\centering
\begin{tabular}{c}
Text
\end{tabular}
\caption{Example}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is it also possible to keep the list of tables in the Contents in boldface without the dots?

Comment: the space after the "list of tables" heading is larger than that after "contents, which looks inappropriate.

Comment: In addition, the bibliography I use is also set in boldface and on the same level as the chapters. Any idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 I am not sure what you want, but did you try `bibliography=leveldown`?

Comment: I think you second example is of the layout I want. Sorry, that I did not recognize this earlier. However, I'm not able to reproduce you layour with the renewcommand. I want to use listoffigures instead of listoftables, but I only get the standard layout.